# Validating image data in vue js using vform api

Tags: vue.js, laravel-vue

I am struggling to validate my data that has images using vue js and vform. My problem is, I am getting an error app.js:2137 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: objectToFormData is not a function. How to rectify this:
In Vue

```js
      saveImageData(){
              var self=this;
              const config = {
                    headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
                }
                document.getElementById('upload-file').value=[];
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('title', this.form.title);
                formData.append('price', this.form.price);
                for(let i=0;i<this.form.images.length;i++){
                 formData.append('images[]', this.form.images[i]);
                }
            this.form.submit('post', '/senddata', {
              // Transform form data to FormData
              transformRequest: [function (formData, headers) {
                return objectToFormData(formData)
              }],
```

In app.js

```js
    window.Vue = require('vue');
    import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from 'vform'
    import {objectToFormData} from 'object-to-formdata'
    window.Form=Form;
    window.objectToFormData=objectToFormData;
```

Comment: Did you import `objectToFormData` like you did in `app.js`?

Comment: @Adam I ran npm install then imported in app.js. In my backend am using Laravel controller

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is having a similar problem i just replaced objecttoformdata with serialize in app js and vue template

```
import {serialize} from "object-to-formdata";
window.serialize=serialize;
```